# 429 ошибка в стиме с прокси

Tags: python, requests, proxy, steam

Отправляю запросы в стим и сразу получаю 429 ошибку, а спустя некоторое время блокируется мой ip. Прокси купленные.
Каким образом стим может узнать мой ip?

```
proxies = {'http':f'http://ip:port@login:pass'} 
request = requests.get('https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/StatTrak%E2%84%A2%20Galil%20AR%20%7C%20Eco%20%28Field-Tested%29/render/?query=&start=0&count=100&country=RU&language=english&currency=5&filter=%22Sticker%22', proxies=proxies, headers={'User-Agent': ua.random},timeout=10)
print(request.status_code)
```

https и socks5h в прокси тоже пробовал.